# Polynomial equation should be easy to solve for $c$ given $c \ne 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

So I am reviewing questions for a probability exam tomorrow, and have paused on the following

> Let $X$ be such that $\mathbf{P}(X=1) = p = 1 - \mathbf{P}(X = -1)$. **Find** $c \ne 1$ such that $\mathbf{E}(c^X) = 1$

For sake of time, I'll spare rewriting the work which leads to the following conclusion that the equation to solve for $c$ is (given $c \ne 1$), 
$$\mathrm{E}[c^X]=1=c^{-1}(1-p)+ cp$$

This is surely easy to solve, but I am nearing my final 1/2 hour for today and tomorrow is the exam. At the moment, I just don't see or recall how to solve this.

We are expected to solve these kinds of equations by hand (i.e. no [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B%281-p%29c%5E%28-1%29%2bc%20p==1,%20c%20!=%201,%20p%20%3E%200%7D,c%5D) and arguably we shouldn't have to rely on it for solving equations like these)

My next step to solve for $c$:

$$1=c^{-1}(1-p)+ cp \implies \frac{1}{c}-\frac{p}{c}+cp - 1 = 0$$

What next? This looks to be almost a chance to solve with the [Quadratic Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticEquation.html), 
$$
c^{-1}(1-p) +cp - 1 = 0
$$

Assuming it's valid to multiply both sides by the variable $c$ (I don't remember whether it is), I get
$$
\tag{1} c^2p - 1 + 1 - p = 0 \implies c^2 p - p = 0
$$

Now, one question I have so far is, have I made a mistake anywhere in this work up to here?. If my work is correct, then I am having trouble seeing whether my answer is equivalent to my [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B%281-p%29c%5E%28-1%29%2bc%20p==1,%20c%20!=%201,%20p%20%3E%200%7D,c%5D)'s answer:

$$\tag{2} c = \frac{1}{p} - 1, p \ne 0, p \ne 1, c \ne 1$$

If my work is incorrect, please point out the mistakes. But if my work is correct and   my answer is indeed equivalent to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B%281-p%29c%5E%28-1%29%2bc%20p==1,%20c%20!=%201,%20p%20%3E%200%7D,c%5D)'s answer, then what are the next algebraic transformations I need to get from **(1)** to **(2)**? It should be obvious to see for sure, but I'm at the end of my day, and not seeing how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in the simplification. When you multiplied through by $c$, you should have obtained $c^2p-c+(1-p)=0$. This is a quadratic equation in $c$, and can be solved using the Quadratic Formula.

In fact, the quadratic factors nicely, as $(c-1)(pc-(1-p))$.

Comment: I see that mistake on multiplying through by $c$ (although my post has yet to be updated). I am not sure what insight led you to that factorization, so I instead corrected my work then took the straightforward approach to solve the quadratic equation, giving $c = 1 \pm \frac{(1-2p)}{2p}$. Hopefully I'm nearing the correct answer

Comment: The factorization comes from the fact that $c=1$ is an obvious (albeit forbidden) solution, so $c-1$ is a factor. alternately, the product of the roots is $(1-p)/p$, and one of the roots is $1$, so the other is $(1-p)/p$. Your expression has a typo, it should be $\frac{1\pm (2p-1)}{2p}$.